# django simple history doesn't show in admin

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I have followed the [Django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html) documentation to display history from the admin page but somehow the history doesn't seem to appear from the admin page. I am using Django version 3.1.2

Here is my admin

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin
from .models import Company

admin.site.register(Company, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

Comment: Have you added the simple_history app in the installed apps in settings and the simple history middleware settings middleware?

Comment: yes i have added it

Comment: can you share the `Company` model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

Suppose you have only one field in your `Company` model i.e `name` field so the model will look as follows:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now import the `HistoricalRecords` class from `simple_history.models` and add the history field in the `Company` model.

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now create a class named `CompanyHistoryAdmin` in `admin.py` by inheriting the `SimpleHistoryAdmin` class after importing it from `simple_history.admin`. see below code:

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin
from .models import Company

# Register your models here.
class CompanyHistoryAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name']
    history_list_display = ['status']
    search_fields = ['name']

admin.site.register(Post, CompanyHistoryAdmin)
```

The `list_display` list will display the records in the form of rows and two columns i.e `id` & `name` in the admin section.
using `search_fields` you can search the records in admin section by the name or any other field you provide.
And `history_list_display` will show the status of any record that you want to see.
To see the history of the record click on any record and then click the history button on the right handside top corner.

More information [read the docs.](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#displaying-custom-columns-in-the-admin-history-list-view)

Comment: Thank you vm. This helped me make the history customized the way I wanted.