# How to make a history for django operations

Tags: django

How to make a history view in Django that show user, time of modification/creation, the previous value and the updated/created value?
and how to track user operation in all system to make insert to history table?

I want the table like this.

| # | time | user | operation | field | previous values | new values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-1-16 | Ali | create | [title](https://#) | null | New Record |
|  | 10:10:10 |  |  |  |  |  |

when I click to link it forward me to page that field has been created ,Updated or deleted.

Comment: You can use `django_simple_history` for that. see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64987344/12132509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at:
[django-auditlog](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-auditlog/) It seems to be very similar to what you need.

As [Ajay Lingayat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698884/how-to-make-a-history-for-django-operations#comment116160263_65698884) suggests, django_simple_history was my first thought too, but it doesn't provide you with the information which fields were changed.

The [SAI SANTOSH CHIRAG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699082/14033765) has at least two problems:

- you have one history model for all your models, which may be problematic in many ways;
- you need to call this every time explicitly and you will forget it.

If you try this approach, I would advice you at least to create a new Model base class, which integrates the history by overriding the save() and delete() methods and than inherit from your class, instead directly from django.models.Model.

Comment: Thanks. If I use history model approach. How I can make forward to page that field was added , updated or deleted?

Comment: The question is surprising. It depends on your system, requirements, user experience etc. You may use Django Admin or create custom views working with your history models.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function (not view) which takes  parameters. And create a new table(model) to store the operations. Let it be `History`

```
class History(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    type = models.CharField()
    prev = models.CharField()
    new = models.CharField()
    field = models.CharField()
```

Whenever you run a CRUD operation, call this below function by inserting appropriate values like operation, field and values

```
def history(user,operation,field,previous,new):
     History.objects.create(user=request.user,type=operation,field=field,prev = previous,new = new)
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this ,what I need is how to create recorder in database, at obj.save() for any model

Comment: Also, if the operation is update how to get updated records only?

Comment: If the operation is update, before the operation, store the data to a new variable and after the operation store the data to another variable, and then send the data to the function

Comment: yes you are right, but I want to overwrite save method because I have  a large number of operations.

Comment: Try: `obj.save(commit=False)` then below write your operations and then save again